# How come at the bottom left corner of my website, it shows a smiley face then it disappears?

Tags: personal-website

As the title suggests, i noticed a smiley face at the bottom left corner of my site for about a couple days but it disappeared not too long ago. The thing is i checked my editor  to see where the smiley face was in the templates, but couldn't see it at all. No one has my password or anything like that so, is this normal? possible hack? im just curious why that happened.

Comment: Well, it doesnt seem normal. Whats the last edit date on the file?

Comment: It was about 2 days ago, because i remember adding an extra ad unit on the single post of the templates and when i scrolled down the page, this smiley was on the left bottom corner. What bothered me was that while it was visible at the time, i couldnt find it in the templates so i can remove it, now its gone but i cant help question why that happened.

Comment: Is this a Wordpress website?

Comment: yes it is actually.

Comment: Sorry but you have not provided enough information for members of the community to give good answers without guessing what the problem could be. The question is most likely more suitable on Stack Overflow due to the nature of the problem (Coding) or security stack if you believe the server has been hacked. Each stack have their own rules and faq that you're need to read before re-posting (Tip: use firebug or chrome and right click the element and click inspect element, its that code they will need). Also a website URL is helpful too.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a Wordpress plugin called `WordPress Stats` (or a similar plugin that emulates it), then you should know that it uses a small smiley face image to gather traffic statistics (or at least, it used to). This is often placed in the footer. It can be hidden with:

```
img#wpstats {
     display: none;
}
```

PS: They may have an option to disable this.